# How do I load XML into a List component in MXML Flash Builder 4?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder

How do I load XML from a local file into a List component in MXML Flash Builder 4?

I tried using Actionscript to create a loader, but I can't seem to add an event listener to the loader.  I've tried to create a local service but I couldn't get that to work either.

I'm making an XML driven AIR app. I plan on having multiple XML files being used - some for content and some for storing settings, state etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTTPService.  Check out an example in Tour de Flex:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=12700;illustIndex=0;docIndex=0

Comment: Local works if the app is on the desktop (Adobe AIR).  Otherwise the user needs to upload it.